# Visual Studio 2017 TFS Integration - .net Core 2

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

I've recently started using .NET Core 2.0 in Visual Studio 2017, and noticed that Pending Changes (I'm using TFS) does not pick up when I add/delete/rename/move a file through the Solution Explorer. It does however detect when i modify the contents of a file that has already been added to source control. As a workaround I have been going to source explorer and doing the action there instead. Is this a known issue, I've searched around and can not find anything about it.

Comment: Are you using local workspaces or server workspaces?

Comment: local workspaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the local workspace, first please double check if the newly added files located in the **Detected** like the following picture:

[image]

If so, then you need to select the change and click “Promote”, the new files will show in the **Included** Changes and Source Control Explorer, you could click check in to check the change in at that time.

Then suggest you give a try with some other project/solutions to narrow down if  the issue related to the particular project/solution.  If so, try to remove TFS source control bindings for them and re-add it. If not,try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/).

If all of the above not work, please update your Visual Studio 2017 to [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes), which may do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it appears to have been the bindings.